# putExtra() not working for Button:onClick

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclick

I have 2 activities and I'm trying put values from the first one into the second one. In the first activity, I created a button with onClick parameter.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/naviButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="navigate"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="startNavigation"/>
```

Then I created 2 methods in Activity SelectedDock: onCreate and startNavigation

```
public void startNavigation (View view) {
    Intent GPSintent = new Intent(SelectedDock.this, GPSActivity.class);
    String XCorValue = "What's wrong with you?!";
    GPSintent.putExtra("SelectedXCor", XCorValue);
    startActivity(GPSintent);
```

In the GPSActivity I have:

```
public class GPSActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
    TextView XCorTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    XCorTV.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("SelectedXcor"));
}
}
```

And in my app I see nothing. Any text. If I remove .setText I can see default value of TextView. I used a tutorial for that and a simple code works, but for mine.. not. What is wrong?
I have to add that SelectedDock is third Activity in my project and for the first and second, I also used Intent.

Comment: Its a typo, the key is `SelectedXCor` and not `SelectedXcor`. The 'C' is upper case in `startNavigation` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GPSintent.putExtra("SelectedXCor", XCorValue);

XCorTV.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("SelectedXcor"));
```

Instead of hardcoding "SelectedXCor", use a final static variable in a different class so that you can use that variable in the whole application minimizing such mistakes.

Make a class named "IntentKeys" and declare a variable

```
public static final String KEYCORE = "SelectedXCor";
```

Now use wherever you want them,

```
GPSintent.putExtra(IntentKeys.KEYCORE, XCorValue);

XCorTV.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(IntentKeys.KEYCORE));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution and the advice.

Answer (score 1):

you are pass **SelectedXCor** as a key in `putExtra` and **SelectedXcor** retrieving with different key that's why you are not retrieving data

just change this `XCorTV.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("SelectedXCor"));
}`

**sample code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
    TextView XCorTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    XCorTV.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("SelectedXCor"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I still forgot about this simple rule. However, I used strings as names for other String objects earlier and everything was correct. In my case it was for ListView items.

Answer (score 0):

getIntent().getExtras. return you a Bundle .

try this ,getIntent().getStringExtra("SelectedXCor");

you will get the String ;